# Flex datagrid headerColor style is not working

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, coding-style, header

I am trying to change the datagrid header color by editing headerColor style. I could change the font size, font family...etc except the headerColor. Would someone help me about it? Thanks a lot.

My code

Mxml

```
<mx:DataGrid id="dataGrid" creationComplete="dataGrid_creationCompleteHandler(event)" dataProvider="{cityinfoResult3.lastResult}">
<mx:columns>
<mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Detail" dataField="detail"/>
<mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Name" dataField="name"/>
</mx:columns>
</mx:DataGrid>
```

Style

```
#dataGrid{
headerColors: #ff6600;    //everything works except this one. The color can't be                  
                          //changed?
rollOverColor: #33ccff;
textRollOverColor: #ffffff;
iconColor: #ff0000;
fontFamily: Arial;
fontSize:12;
dropShadowEnabled: true;
alternatingItemColors: #330099, #0000cc;
color: #ffffff;
borderColor: #ffffff;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

headerColors needs an array of 2 items in order to draw a gradient.  If you want a solid color, I bet something likethis would work:

```
headerColors: #ff6600, #ff6600 ;
```

Comment: Ty for helping me again. I tried your code but it gave me style syntax error. I used "headerColors: #ff6600, #ffffff ;" The error is gone but the color can't be changed either...:(

Comment: headerColors is only supported in Flex 4 if you're using the Halo theme.  So you may need to add the compiler argument -theme=${flexlib}/themes/Halo/halo.swc .  Once I did that; the colors showed up.

Comment: hm...I believe I have to add it like below..
-locale en_US -theme=${flexlib}/themes/Halo/halo.swc. The compiler gave me many warning that said "The style "borderColor" is only supported by type 'spark.component.panel' with the theme spark" and can't render my application....

Comment: Sounds like you're having problems mixing Halo and Spark, then.  See if you can create a custom button skin with your gradient in Flash Pro and then use that skin as the headerSkin .

Comment: I thought skin can only apply in spark component. Datagrid is mx component.

Comment: man...This really drive me crazy. The borderThickness style is not working in Flex 4 either....what's going on? :(...

Comment: Most mx components have a 'skin' style.  Just the skinning process is very different in Halo and Spark.  I'm glad you got it working.

Comment: ya. the main problem here is the halo theme and spark. Don't know why they want to separate them.

Comment: @Jerry It would be nice if you shared your findings with us in an answer.

Answer (score 1):

In Flex's CSS, you don't want the [] brackets around your values (though you *would* want them if you were doing this in straight-up ActionScript).

This should do the trick:

`headerColors: #ff6600, #ff6600;`

Answer (score 1):

For an mx DataGrid, create a new skin mxml (s:SparkSkin) and copy the mx.skins.spark.DataGridHeaderBackgroundSkin code into your custom skin class.

Find the code snippet below and replace the values with your chosen colours.

```
<!-- layer 2: fill -->
<s:Rect left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0">
    <s:fill>
        <s:LinearGradient rotation="90">
            <s:GradientEntry color="0xFFFFFF" 
                             alpha="0.85" />
            <s:GradientEntry color="0xD8D8D8" 
                             alpha="0.85" />
        </s:LinearGradient>
    </s:fill>
</s:Rect>
```

In your DataGrid component, point the header background skin to your custom skin:

```
<mx:DataGrid id="dataGrid" headerBackgroundSkin="assets.skins.CustomDataGridSkin">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
dataGrid.setStyle("headerColors", ["red", "blue"]);
```